# awk printing help cshell script

Tags: shell, awk

I have sql script :

```
SPOOL &1

Select to_char(min(calen_dt),'mm-dd-YY') FD,
       to_char(max(calen_dt),'mm-dd-YY') LD
from put_calen
where calen_dt >= trunc(sysdate,'mm') - interval '1' month
and calen_dt <= trunc(sysdate,'mm') - interval '1' day
and business_day_ind = 'Y';

SPOOL OFF
```

that dumps it output to get.tmp

my question is how can i set min and max date in my cshell script so i can use that date.. the way i did it.. it didnt work.. what i need to change here

```
sqlplus $ORA_UID/$ORA_PSWD @${SQL}example.sql ${TMP}get.tmp
set first_date=`cat ${TMP}/get_date.tmp | awk -F '{print $1}'`
echo 'First Date: '${first_date}
set last_date=`cat ${TMP}/get_date.tmp  | awk -F '{print $2}'`
echo 'Last Date: '${last_date}
```

Comment: Can you please put at least one sample line of what your input looks like and the value you would like to retrieve from it.  This would be extremely helpful to get you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: plz.. can somebody help me.. i really need to fix this.. but dont know how it works in a delimiter file

Comment: Sorry, per SiegeX comment, still not clear what the data in get_date.tmp looks like. Otherwise we're only guessing. ALSO, it's not clear;... do you use the SQL code posted as part of the process you want to fix OR are you showing us the SQL code because it has date calculations that you need to re-create in csh OR are you trying to parse the output in get_date.tmp? Every week there is a question about how to do date calculations in shell. Just search for that. OR Change your posting to show 1. before, 2. after, 3. why it is wrong. 4 what you are doing, please ;-)!  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specifically need awk for some other reason, I'd suggest using cut instead :

```
set f1=grep G1 ${TMP}/get.tmp | cut -d= -f2
```

I also took the liberty of removing the leading 'cat' since grep may as well take the file from the command line

Comment: In any shell, you need command substitution to assign a value to a var, i.e. set f1=\`grep ...\`. Backticks are required per the OP's csh requirement.